# match a string of characters between tags:

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following strings:

```
&#60;PAUL SAINT-KARL 1997-05-07&#62;
&#60;BOB DEAN 2001-05-07&#62;
&#60;GUY JEDDY 2007-05-07&#62;
```

I want a java regex that would match this type of pattern "name and date" and then extract the name and date separately.

I able to match them separately with the following java regex:

```
   1) (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})&#62;

   2)  &#60;([ A-Z&#;0-9-]*+)
```

What I'm looking for is one regex that would identify the full text pattern as provided, and then extract the subsections, such as the actual name, and the date.

I'm looking to use Matcher.group() to retrieve the complete match from the target string.

Thanks

Comment: Is this supposed to work on RADIX-50 only, or on Unicode (Java’s native character set)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
"&#60;([ A-Z&#;0-9-]*?) (\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})&#62;"
```

I changed the `*+` to `*?` to make the `*` match lazily.

Comment: Yes, I did, and somehow it doesn't seem to find the pattern.  However, doing them separately works: Regex: (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})&#62;
and capturing the text via a placeholder: <date v="$1"/>
Regex: 
&#60;([ A-Z&#;0-9-]*+)
and capturing the text via a placeholder:<author v="$1"/>